# Programmatically add product in cart - empty cart

Tags: php, magento, cart

I'm trying to add a product in cart but the cart stay empty.
Here's my code

```
try{
    $product_model = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product');

    // Load product
    $_sku = "1-574#AD-B00731";
    $my_product_id  = $product_model->getIdBySku($_sku);
    $my_product     = $product_model->load($my_product_id);
    $qty_value = 1;

    // Add to cart 
    $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
    $cart->init();
    $cart->addProduct($my_product, array('qty' => $qty_value));
    $cart->save();
    print_r($cart->getItemsQty().PHP_EOL);
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
    var_dump("working");
 }
catch(Exception $e){
    return $e->getMessage();
}
```

When I print `$cart->getItemsQty()` my item quantity are incremanting but my cart is still empty. I think it's `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);` that is not working properly.

Anybody have an idea of what is not working?

Edit 1: I use Magento 1.8.0, so via an url query is not working because of the form_key

Answer (score 1):

Try to change

```
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
```

to

```
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
```

Cart is a singleton, because you have only 1 cart on your store for 1 user and all who want to use it can call it as getSingleton, without creating new object. If you use Mage::getModel('checkout/cart') it will create a new object. Ye, it will allow you to save quote to DB, but this will not be current active customer cart.

Comment: How can I get the customer's cart?

Comment: Did you the to change your script as I suggested? To get current customer cart use Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote(); or Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();

Comment: Yes I did and my cart is still empty

Comment: I just overwrited the CartController and now I use the URL methode

Answer (score 1):

You need to refresh the itemcache of the Itemcollection. Because this will also remove the quote-model from it, it must be added after that too

```
$cart->getItems()->clear();
$cart->getItems()->setQuote($cart->getQuote());
```